# How to convert my Android contacts to iPhone?

Tags: ios, contacts

I was using an Android phone which has 1500+ contacts, and I don't want to miss them because now I am using an iPhone and I want to convert all Android phone contacts to iPhone. Is there any solution which can help me?

Answer (score 0):

- Download and launch iTunes.
- Connect your iPhone to the computer.
- Open the handset's device summary page.
- Click the Info tab.
- Check “Sync Contacts With” and then select “Google Contacts”.
- Type your Google account's username and password.
- Click Apply.

Comment: Nobody mentioned Google. Maybe the contacts only exist in the phone itself...

Answer (score 0):

There's an Apple app available on the Google Play Store designed to help you migrate - [Move to iOS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apple.movetoios&hl=en)

From [iMore - How to move your photos, contacts, and more from Android to iPad and iPhone](http://www.imore.com/how-move-your-photos-contacts-and-more-android-iphone) which also has pictures & additional links to Google software available for iOS

> 1. Set up your iPhone or iPad until you reach the screen titled "Apps & Data".
> 2. Tap "Move Data from Android" option.
> 3. On your **Android phone or tablet**, open the **Google Play Store** and search for **Move to iOS**.
> 4. Open the **Move to iOS app listing**.
> 5. Tap **Install**
> 6. Tap to accept the permissions request.
> 7. Tap **Open** after it's installed.
> 8. Tap **Continue** on both devices.
> 9. Tap **Agree** and then **Next** on the Android phone or tablet.
> 10. On your **Android device**, enter the **12-digit code** displayed on the **iPhone** or **iPad**.
>
> After entering the code, the Android device will connect with your
>   iPhone or iPad over a peer-to-peer Wi-Fi connection and determine what
>   data will be transferred.
>
> It will ask whether you want to transfer your Google Account info (so
>   that you can quickly log in on your new Apple device), Chrome
>   bookmarks, text messages, contacts, and the photos and videos in your
>   camera roll. Select everything you want to move over.
>
> Connecting to the iPhoneSelecting what data to transferTransferring
>   data
>
> Your Android phone or tablet will transfer the selected data over to
>   your iPhone or iPad and place the appropriate content into the correct
>   apps. The two devices will disconnect and Android will prompt you to
>   take your old device to the Apple Store, where they'll recycle it for
>   free, although you could just sell it yourself.
>
> Once the transfer process is complete, tap on **Continue Setting Up
>   iPhone** or **Continue Setting Up iPad** on your device and carry on
>   setting up a new Apple ID or logging into your existing one.
>
> Once the setup process is completed, you'll be prompted to log in to
>   the accounts you transferred from your old Android device. Do that,
>   and then you're good to go!